# Search table in 2 fields show first result first

Tags: sql, union

I have a table named Photos (Id, Title, Description, Date, Online).
I want to search the table by Title and Description, but I want see first the results of the Title search and then the results of the Description.

I tried a normal search but don't know how to separate them.

```
SELECT * FROM [Photos] 
WHERE ([Online] = 1) 
AND ([Description] like '%" + querytext + "%') 
OR ([Title] like '%" + querytext + "%') 
ORDER BY [Date] DESC, [Id] DESC
```

Then I tried to do it with the UNION, but didn't work either.

```
SELECT * FROM [Photos] 
WHERE ([Online] = 1) 
AND ([Description] like '%" + querytext + "%') 
UNION 
SELECT * FROM [Photos] 
WHERE ([Online] = 1) 
AND ([Title] like '%" + querytext+ "%') 
ORDER BY [Date] DESC, [Id] DESCBeto
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `CASE` expressions in `ORDER BY` clause:

```
SELECT *
FROM Photos 
WHERE
  Online = 1 
  AND Description like '%" + querytext + "%'
  OR Title like '%" + querytext + "%'
ORDER BY
  CASE WHEN Title like '%" + querytext + "%' THEN 1 ELSE 2 END,
  [Date] DESC,
  [Id] DESC
```

Answer (score 3):

Add some column that will mark rows:

```
SELECT *, 1 AS Mark 
FROM [Photos] 
WHERE ([Online] = 1) 
AND ([Title] like '%" + querytext + "%') 
UNION ALL
SELECT *, 2 AS Mark 
FROM [Photos] 
WHERE ([Online] = 1) 
AND ([Description] like '%" + querytext+ "%') 
ORDER BY Mark, [Date] DESC, [Id] DESC
```

Comment: Don't you need to order by Mark as well?

Comment: Yes, and dont you need put both in a subquery?

Comment: @Fred, of course you need. Thank you for spotting this.

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza, it will work without putting in a subquery

Comment: It repeates the records that have the querytext both in the title and the descrition. Tried to remove the ALL from UNION ALL, but it made no difference.

Answer (score 3):

Just include a `source` field on your `UNION`, put the result in a subquery and sort the subquery.

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT 'Description' as source, * FROM [Photos] 
    WHERE ([Online] = 1) 
    AND ([Description] like '%" + querytext + "%') 
    UNION 
    SELECT 'Title' as source, * FROM [Photos] 
    WHERE ([Online] = 1) 
    AND ([Title] like '%" + querytext+ "%') 
    ) T
ORDER BY source DESC, [Date] DESC, [Id] DESC
```

Comment: Duplicates the records that have the querytext on both the title and the description.

Comment: What about the last upudate from @Kamran Farzami? That looks like is on the right track

Comment: @Humberto Can you share sample data and expected output?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT 'Description' as source, * FROM [Photos] 
    WHERE ([Online] = 1) 
    AND ([Description] like '%" + querytext + "%') 
    UNION 
    SELECT 'Title' as title, * FROM [Photos] 
    WHERE ([Online] = 1) 
    AND ([Title] like '%" + querytext+ "%') 
    ) T
ORDER BY title DESC, [Date] DESC, [Id] DESC
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
SELECT * FROM [Photos] 
WHERE ([Online] = 1) 
AND (([Description] like '%" + querytext + "%') 
OR ([Title] like '%" + querytext + "%')) 
ORDER BY [Date] DESC, [Id] DESC
```

How about this:

```
SELECT *, CASE WHEN ([Description] like '%" + querytext + "%') THEN 1 WHEN ([Title] like '%" + querytext + "%') THEN 2 END AS ord  FROM [Photos] 
WHERE ([Online] = 1) 
AND (([Description] like '%" + querytext + "%') 
OR ([Title] like '%" + querytext + "%')) 
ORDER BY [Date] DESC, [Id] DESC , ord DESC
```

Comment: It gives me the same result them my first code. I need it to apear in the search result first the Titles that match and then the Descriptions that match.

Comment: Kamran you were on the right path, but filiprem solution is simple.